# Selenium Test - Check if url returns a pdf

Tags: pdf, selenium, selenium-rc

I have a selenium test I am creating.  The application creates a pdf for the user.  I want to know how to test that a url returns a pdf file.  I don't really care what is in the pdf, just that one got created.

- FYI - The url does not container .pdf

  http://www.url.com/printp/something.php?pld=b8eiub9w6ar2am1i

Comment: Perhaps check the content_type returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, make a HEAD request first to check if the url is created, then inspect content_length header, which should be nonzero size, or whatever is reasonable minimum size in your case.

Comment: This may be a good choice, will have to do more research on how to actually accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test if //meta[contains(@http-equiv,Content-Type)][contains(@content,pdf)] exists!

I did not test !

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, I tried this.  Problem is a save dialog opens when you click on the download link.  This seems to stop selenium completely and according to their docs, there is no way to control save dialogs.

Comment: http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/Selenium+Core+FAQ#SeleniumCoreFAQ-HowdoIdownloadafile?